# CustomCellView inside List is not resizable, using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I tried to design a custom list item using SwiftUI but it's not working as resizable.

1. Red highlighted is dynamic content to resize `Text`. So the `CustomCell` should be resized as per content (Red highlighted).
2. All three buttons could be hidden as per property `isTranslation` in Model `ItemModel`. So again `CustomCell` should be resized.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Example Screenshot -**

[image]

**Below is the code: -**

**Parent ContentView**

```
struct ParentView: View {
    
    private let list = ItemModel.list
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView {
                
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                    CustomCell(item: item)
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 1, y: 1)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Nav Title", displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct ItemModel: Decodable, Hashable {
    var sno: String
    var content: String
    var reference: String
    var isTranslation: Bool
    
    static let list: [ItemModel] = Bundle.main.decode(fileName: "items.json")
}
```

**Custom Cell View**

```
struct CustomCell: View {
    
    var item: ItemModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            VStack {
                Text("\(item.sno)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 1, y: 1)
            }
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                Text("\(item.content)")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 150, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("\(item.reference)")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
            }
            
            if item.isTranslation {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TextButtonView(title: "Button 1", color: Color.lightGray, radius: 1)
                    Spacer()
                    TextButtonView(title: "Button 2", color: Color.lightGray, radius: 1)
                    Spacer()
                    TextButtonView(title: "Button 3", color: Color.lightGray, radius: 1)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
//        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 150, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding(8)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}

struct CustomCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomCell(item: ItemModel.list.first!)
    }
}
```

**Bottom 3 Buttons View**

```
struct CustomTextButtonView: View {
    
    var title: String
    var color: Color
    var radius: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(title)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .background(color)
            .cornerRadius(4)
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: radius, x: 1, y: 1)
    }
}
```

**Json file: -**

```
[
  {
    "sno": "1",
    "content": "Now, let’s add a brand new view to our project which is going to be presented when user taps the bell button.",
    "reference": "SheetView",
    "isTranslation": true
  },
  {
    "sno": "2",
    "content": "Now, let’s add a brand new view to our project which is going to be presented when user taps the bell button. We’re going to call it a SheetView and it’s also going to be a NavigationView with a title. In this case, the title of the navigation bar is styled to be displayed inline (in the middle of the navigation bar)",
    "reference": "let’s add a brand new view",
    "isTranslation": true
  },
  {
    "sno": "3",
    "content": "SwiftUI’s sheets are used to present new views over existing ones, while still allowing users to drag down to dismiss the new view when they are ready.         To use a sheet, give it something to show (some text, an image, a custom view, etc), add a Boolean that defines whether the detail view should be showing, then attach it to your main view as a modal sheet.         For example, this creates a simple detail view, then presents it from ContentView when a button is tapped:",
    "reference": "Hello",
    "isTranslation": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "minHeight: 150" with text
It will take atleast 150 height no matter how short that text is. Remove minHeight, it will work fine.

for unlimited lines of text, you can use this

```
Text("")
 .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```